# original mario on nintendo switch - warp zone to 8?

Tags: super-mario-bros

I've heard that from level 4-2 you can warp to world 8, but when I go up the vine the only tunnel says world 6.  Is this because I'm playing on Nintendo Switch??

Does anyone know why its not giving me the level 8 tunnel?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you playing via the Nintendo Entertainment System app or playing _Arcade Archives Vs. Super Mario Bros._ from the eShop?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the version of *Super Mario Bros.* you are playing isn't the beloved 1985 NES version, but a 1986 **arcade** version called *VS. Super Mario Bros.* Most likely because the NES version is only available through the paid [*Nintendo Switch Online*](https://www.nintendo.com/switch/online-service/nes/) service, while the aracade version is sold in the *Nintendo eShop* as [*Arcade Archives VS. SUPER MARIO BROS.*](https://www.nintendo.com/games/detail/arcade-archives-vs-super-mario-bros-switch/)

This version is different from the original one in [many surprising ways](https://www.mariowiki.com/VS._Super_Mario_Bros.). Some of the changes are there to prevent bugs, like the famous minus world bug. Other, like removing several 1-ups, are to make the game harder. Sometimes entire levels have changed places or are swapped for Lost Levels levels.

The difficulty tweaks includes changing the 4-2 warp zone to only include the warp to World 6. This way players are forced to play through worlds Worlds 6 and 7 which include some really devious levels from Lost Worlds.

Comment: is this about the Arcade Archives version or the version from the Nintendo Entertainment System app?

Comment: @DJSpicyDeluxe For the _Arcade Archives_ version, I'm assuming. I don't actually own a Switch, but the description clearly fits the _VS._-version of _Super Mario Bros._ So unless that's also available in the NES-app, the source of confusin seems clear. (The first paragraph of my answer may need some clarifying, tough.)

Comment: @DJPirtu Nintendo Switch online gives you access to games which includes the NES version of Super Mario Bros.; whereas you can also purchase the Arcade Archives version separately on the e-shop.

Comment: @JMac Thanks. Clarified this in the answer.